# Is it okay to combine 2 "perspective genre"?

Tags: game-design, perspective

I've just started making a RPG and I'm thinking about putting 2 kind of "genre" perspective, like having a Top-Down gameplay for the entire storyline and putting a 2D fighter for the battle scene.

*(e.g: Undertale Top-Down gameplay with Touhouvania 2D Fighter Battle System)*

Is it okay to do this? Will there any problem with the flow of the game that will affects player experience?

Comment: In my opinion, it depends on two things: 1) what do you exactly mean by "okay"? 2) who are your target audience? Are they used to see such a things?

Comment: Game developers have been doing that for decades.

Comment: In what way are you worried this would be "not okay"? What specific potential problem are we trying to address here?

Comment: I am still not so sure as I haven't tested this out, and I haven't see any games that actually do this. Most of the games I see are usually go with a specific flow and went along with it.

Comment: You might want to check out the *Tales of...* franchise by Namco. The earlier games combine classic 2d top-down exploration with side-scrolling real-time combat. The later games then evolved both in a more 3d direction. Regarding the question at hand: *Can* you do this? Sure. *Should* you do this? This is a question for a more debate-oriented community, because it hinges on execution details.